# set default kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, default, default-value, kubeconfig

This is kind of a silly one but, given a number of clusters...

***How would a user specify one cluster to be set as the default?***

```
CURRENT  NAME
*        minikube   
         stage     
         prod
```

Every time I open a new Terminal (macOS), it defaults to *prod*. I know I'm just one misstep away from not paying attention and destroying something valuable.

- If I set `minikube` as the current cluster, then open new tabs in the same Terminal window, `minikube` remains the default.
- If I were to Quit the Terminal altogether and reopen it, it would default back to `prod`.

Anecdotally, I've used [ktx](https://github.com/vmware-archive/ktx) forever and never had this issue. Recently tried [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) and this is the first time I've noticed the behavior. I don't see anything in their docs about setting a default cluster so seems unlikely.

If anyone knows how to set a default cluster, please advise.

Comment: These configs are written to ~/.kube/config file. So it is possible that when you restart your terminal and bash_profile or bashrc files (depending on your shell) are executed, they are somehow changing that config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `kubectl`, the command `kubectl config use-context` might help.
In your case :

```
kubectl config use-context minikube
```

Comment: that changes it for sure; what I can't understand is *after* I change it, then Quit/reopen the Terminal, why it changes back to the prod cluster.

Comment: Does your ~/.kube/config contains `current-context: prod` ?
Do you use the correct kubeconfig ?

Comment: I've changed it to minikube (again), but yes; I grep'd for `current-context` and found minikube designated.

Comment: With the right value set of current-context, you should have kubectl defaulting to minikube. If this is not the case, try to specify explicitely your kubeconfig with `kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config`.
Make sure as well that `kubectl config current-context` outputs the right context.